# compound queries in elasticsearch, java api

Tags: java, json, api, elasticsearch, search

How to make compound query, as example I need to find geojson data with some properties (these properties is set in search query) within some polygon?

I know there are the GeoPolygonQueryBuilder and the BoolQueryBuilder for these kind of requests, but how to use them together in a single request to fetch data from ES?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is a shot in the dark, because your question is lacking a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) or even pseudo-code. If you are asking how to write a query that combines two sub queries, use the `BoolQueryBuilder` and provide multiple mandatory sub queries:

```
final BoolQueryBuilder query = new BoolQueryBuilder()
        .must(new GeoPolygonQueryBuilder(
                   "geo_field",
                   List.of(new GeoPoint(14, 50), …)))
        .must(new GeoPolygonQueryBuilder(
                   "geo_field",
                   List.of(new GeoPoint(14, 50), …)));
```

`BoolQueryBuilder` has additional methods such as `mustNot`, `should`, or `filter`.